# How to get all javascript source links from a website url when the page download

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to check a website if it uses a special online js source(for example, fontawesome).

By the way, some can be found only when it's loaded, not from website source html. I tried with puppeteer, but it takes long time. I think the reason is that it loads other resources like images.

Is there any solution for this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: usually I hava a hack around to use Selenium, which comes also in Nodejs. After some adjusting search you are able to generate what ever you looking for. Works also for huge search data online.

Comment: I'm making an api for this. So it should be done on server, with headless browser testing. I tried with selenium and not sure if it's the right solution.

Comment: otherwise try gulp or webpack. both can be added to nodejs than on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom)

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
(async function() {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();
  await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
    console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
  });

  const status = await page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  const content = await page.property('content');
  console.log(content);

  await instance.exit();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the source you can do this within most browsers Chrome for example  if you press Control+ Shift+I then select the sources tab , this will give you the sources of the web page. Are you looking for a script to automate this process?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes. I'm going to do this on node app. Is there any npm for this?